# Probability of the ratio of two sequences of iid normal random variables whose means go to infinity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Let $X_m, Y_m $ be iid $\mathcal{N}(m, 1)$ random variables. Let $m \to \infty.$

I feel the following are true: for every fixed $\epsilon > 0$

1. $$lim _{m \to \infty} P[1 < \frac{X_m}{Y_m} < 1 + \epsilon] =  lim _{m \to \infty} P[1 - \epsilon  < \frac{X_m}{Y_m} < 1 ] $$

and

2. $$ lim _{m \to \infty}  P[1-\epsilon < \frac{X_m}{Y_m} < 1 + \epsilon] = lim _{m \to \infty} \left( P[1 < \frac{X_m}{Y_m} < 1 + \epsilon] +  P[1 - \epsilon  < \frac{X_m}{Y_m} < 1 ] \right )=1$$

(So in essence, does $\frac{X_m}{Y_m} \to_{p}1?$)

I feel so because when $m$ is large enough, with a high probability, both $X_m, Y_m$ are concentrated around their common mean $m,$ so with a high probability, their ratio is concentrated near $1.$ If true, this would show that second statement. But I'm not completely sure how to go about proving the first one, even intuitively. Some help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Focusing on Q1, I think it may be easier to analyze if you rewrite the events as the difference of Normal rvs $X_m$ and $Y_m$. For instance $\{X_m/Y_m>1\} = \{ Y_m>0, \; X_m-Y_m>0\} \cup \{Y_m<0, X_m - Y_m < 0\}$. Then we can use the fact that linear combination of normal rvs are also normal.

Comment: @panini Thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure how one'd write the event $\{1- \epsilon < X_m/Y_m < 1+\epsilon\}= \{0 < \frac{X_m - Y_m}{Y_m} < \epsilon \}$ using any just the normality of $X_m-Y_m$ alone? I'd appreciate if you write down your argument in detail?